# Can I prevent my spider plant from growing more leaves?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, bonsai

I have a spider plant (*chlorophytum comosum*) that I have raised since he was still attached to his parent.  He is in a small (2 inch diameter) pot and lives on my desk in indirect sunlight all day, growing like a champ.  Today I noticed he began his eight leaf.

I would like him to stop at eight leaves.  Is there any way I can stop or discourage further leaf growth while keeping the plant alive?

Comment: I don't think that idea likely to be a success. Spider plants will fill at 12 inch pot in a few years if they are growing well! If you want a small slow growing plant, choose a small variety of succulent, and give it the minimum amount of water. Something like a lithops will grow (and flower) in a 2 inch pot for years.

Comment: I would find another plant, low light, loves being forgotten, gets along under office lighting.  Up pot that baby in potting soil only. Get a plant stand to be beside your desk?  Unless you make a spider plant bonsai this idea is not healthy for your 'baby'...and that won't happen, grins.  Take the plant home and put it in your kitchen or near a south window not in direct sun.  Get another plant...indoor plants are considered 'long term perishables'.  Taking them out of doors under a covered patio or porch for the summer is the best way to rejuvenate them and keep them looking lush.

Comment: @stormy I specifically want a spider plant with eight leaves.  Can I 'bonsai' the plant?  How would I do that?

Comment: MackM, I am pretty sure that the “spider plant bonsai” was just a bit of irony.

Comment: I am sorry, my bonsai remark was a bit of irony, thanks Stephie.  In the natural world the ability to adapt and honor all other lives is paramount for maturity and HAPPINESS.  To mature we all learn how impotent we are trying to control anything.  Learning to go with the flow opens doors we never knew existed that are full of sights, sounds, smells that to any human are vastly exciting!  Rethink your needs, consider the need of this one plant and also envision a NEW plant in its place.  Like rearranging furniture?  Spices up life big time.